# Obtained keyed collection from query builder object

Tags: laravel, eloquent

```
$current_laptops = Laptop::where($request->IDs);
```

From the above, I want to get a collection or array that is keyed by the record IDs. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`keyBy()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-keys) to get a collection that is keyed by the record IDs as:

```
$current_laptops = Laptop::whereIn('id', ['1', '2'])->get();

$current_laptops = $current_laptops->keyBy('id')
```

> The `keyBy` method keys the collection by the given key. If multiple
>   items have the same key, only the last one will appear in the new
>   collection

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
$id_arr = $request->IDs; // This should be an array of ids
$current_laptops = Laptop::whereIn('column_name', $id_arr)->get();
```

Then you can use [`keyBy`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-keyby) like this:

```
$keyed_records = $current_laptops->keyBy('id');
```

Or by using [`pluck()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-pluck):

```
$keyed_records = $current_laptops->pluck('name', 'id');
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you have array or collection of IDs, you need to use `whereIn()`. Also you need to use `pluck()` to get keyed collection:

```
$current_laptops = Laptop::whereIn('id', $request->IDs)->pluck('name', 'id');
```

This query will find records with defined IDs and will create collection where `id` is the key and `name` is it's value.

Comment: I need to 'pluck' more than one field though. I need location_id and user.